# How to use Angular ng-options other than on a select element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selection

The official docs say that we can use ng-options on any element, not just the [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). I figure we can do this so that we can make the selection UI look better (especially if we want to display a thumbnail image or provide more info than just from one property).

I've tried it without success. My object is a player with two properties - name and number:

```
    <div ng-model="selectedPlayer" ng-options="player.name for player in players">
        {{player.name}} - his number is {{player.number}}
    </div>
```

I've loaded the list in a controller, which I don't need to show for brevity. This doesn't work. It'll just display "{{player.name}} - his number is {{player.number}}" literally, just once.

I'm thinking that my markup is wrong or missing something. The thing is, a select element actually has options which I believe ng-options render the data into. My div doesn't have that, so I don't know what to do.

The "ugly" alternative is to use ng-repeat and hook up an item to a function (onSelect(player)) of the controller:

```
    <div ng-repeat="player in players">
        {{player.name}} - his number is {{player.number}} <span ng-click="onSelect(player)" />
    </div>
```

I don't think I'll need the ng-model then because that would be taken care of by the controller's onSelect(player) function. I don't want to do this, though!

So again, how do we use ng-options besides on a select element - without messing with the controller to do the selected item binding?

Comment: can you link to the section of the docs where you read this? As far as I'm aware, ngOptions can be strictly used with the select element

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions under the Usage section says ANY for the tag.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is just the generic example usage for an attribute. The heading of that page would suggest it can only be used on `select` "The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of <option> elements for the <select> element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression."

Comment: OK, so "selective reading" got me. It still threw me off why they said ANY tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are incorrect, see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0-rc.1/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L363

Select is required for ng-options. ng-repeat is the correct solution for your task.